# D3D12 Tiled Resources Tier 4

Tags: direct3d12

On https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/ne-d3d12-d3d12_tiled_resources_tier are four possible tiers for Tiled Resources. But the fourth tier is undocumented in contrast to the others, so I can't figure out what this tier is for. What additional features does tier 4 offer? Which GPUs support tier 4? And since which Shader Model/Windows 10/WDDM version is this tier available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `D3D12_TILED_RESOURCES_TIER4` enum was added for Windows 10 SDK (17134) as an experimental value, but to date it's never been implemented nor does any current hardware support it.

> You can also look at the public [specs](https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/), but this particular question isn't addressed in those docs.

Comment: 1. What additional features does Tier 4 offer? 2. Is Tier 4 still experimental with the Windows 10.0.19041 SDK?

Comment: According to the beyond3D guys that [maintain](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Feature_levels_in_Direct3D&diff=864237515&oldid=863891348) the wikipedia page, it should correspond to Tier 3 plus [*texture tile data-inheritance*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/memory-aliasing-and-data-inheritance#data-inheritance), and it [should be](https://forum.beyond3d.com/threads/direct3d-feature-levels-discussion.56575/page-47) available at least on new nvidia cards when you set Windows into developer mode.